# Java disable other vue when my variable is equals to a specific number

Tags: java

I have a variable with 4 values possibles : `1,2,3 and 4`

I woudlike to do a function to disable my view in javafx.

example 1 : my variable equals 1 so disable 2,3 and 4
example 2 : if my variable equals 3 so siable 1,2 and 4

Java :

```
int valueType = 3;

if (valueType==1 || valueType==2 || valueType ==4)anchorpaneView.getChildren().get(i).setVisible(false);
```

Is it possible to have a generic function to do this ?

Comment: If it can only have 4 values: `if (valueType != 3)`. Otherwise, please can you specify what needs to be generic?